# MAPI32.dll throwing error in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8.1, mapi, .net-framework-version

I have a winform application in .Net Framework 3.5. Now i am trying to upgrade it to .Net Framework 4.5 and target platform as windows 8.1.
Problem is that the project using MAPI32.dll to open default Mail client with attachment. it was working fine with old verson i.e. in 3.5 frameowrk. But it is throwing an error in upgraded version.

Error is like

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in MyProj.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Update: Error is happening when adding attachment.

Comment: What line of code fires the exception?